# Code for reading an XML file into a DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have written the following piece of code that reads through a given xml-file and writes the contents into a data-table. Please do NOT suggest to use LinqToXml as that option is ruled because this is a legacy application.

```
            // create the DataTable that will hold the data
            DataTable table = new DataTable("ListOfPersonsWithInfo");


            // open the file using a Stream
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileNameWithAbsolutePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // create the table with the appropriate column names
                table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
                table.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(String));
                table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(String));

                // use ReadXml to read the XML stream
                table.ReadXml(stream);

                // tried with this overload-option as well but didnt help
                //table.ReadXml(fileNameWithAbsolutePath);

                // return the results
                return table;
            }
```

**BUT the returned-table contains ZERO rows...!!! where as the actual xml file has '3 rows' and is structured as follows (ANY IDEA what is going wrong here?):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Details>
    <EachPerson>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <ImagePathAndFileName>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg</ImagePathAndFileName>
        <Address>NewYork</Address>
    </EachPerson>
    <EachPerson>
        <Name>Tom</Name>
        <ImagePathAndFileName>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg</ImagePathAndFileName>
        <Address>London</Address>
    </EachPerson>
    <EachPerson>
        <Name>Jill</Name>
        <ImagePathAndFileName>C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg</ImagePathAndFileName>
        <Address>Tokyo</Address>
    </EachPerson>
</Details>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ReadXML

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(fileNameWithAbsolutePath);
        return ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thats it PraVn... but still unable to fathom as to why the dataTABLE.ReadXml() fails but the dataSET.ReadXml() works?... so is there something specific to internal implementation of this ReadXml.

Comment: Yes.<Details> is the root which has three levels which is not possible to load in datatable

Comment: Thanks PraVn... u seem to be having a very clear view of the internal workings of ADO.NET. Just in case if it suits you, can you have a look at my other question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687640/uml-diagram-for-ado-net-components-like-dataadapter-dataset-datatable-etc>. This question nobody has attempted to answer or may be it is too vague for some or could be too time consuming for someone to answer with a diagram).