# Reading XML giving null

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, c#-3.0

```
<tours xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.contiki.com/schemas/v2/detailed_tours.xsd">
<tour>
  <id>290</id>
  <name>Peru Uncovered</name>
  <lowest_price>
    <code>11D15a</code>
  </lowest_price>
 </tour>
</tours>
```

I want to read `Id, name` and `code`. 
I am trying this code

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(downloadfolder);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);

foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
    string employeeName = chldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
}
```

But i am getting null. Can anyone tell me how can i read the values? i can not use Linq as i am working in SSIS 2008 project which does not support linq.

Updated Answer

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(downloadfolder);
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.

            string node = reader.Name;
            if (node == "id")
            {
                string id = reader.ReadString();
            }
            if (node == "name")
            {
                string name = reader.ReadString();
            }
            if (node == "code")
            {
                string code = reader.ReadString();
            }
            break;
    }
```

I can read the values but how can i add these as a row in my data table?

Comment: `name` is a node, not an attribute.

Comment: can you tell me how can i read the node name?

Comment: from the debugger node = version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" and not reading the whole xml

Comment: Just do [`XmlDocument.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and load the entire thing.

Comment: @dbc i cant it says Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Possibly related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here node type of "name" is element.

below code can be used for node type checking

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("<file name>");
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType) 
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
```

Reference : http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307548

Comment: this is very complicated how can i read the value if i find the element name "id" then how can i read the value

Comment: so you wanted to read xml into data-table then check this stack-over flow thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781796/code-for-reading-an-xml-file-into-a-datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781796/code-for-reading-an-xml-file-into-a-datatable)