# How to make an xml file in c# for use with .iqy which imports as a datatable

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I want to make a excel file where the data is collected and updated automatically off my site and display as data tables.

I have tried to web import off the site from a table I have created but it is not formatted as a data table.

I have also created a xml file and used a .iqy file to get the data and still it is not imported as a data table

This is my .iqy file which will import data but not as a xml

```
WEB
1
http://localhost:55369/files/SerializationOverview.xml
```

This is my test xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <bookstore>
      <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
      </book>
      <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
      </book>
      <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>
```

Thank you in advance any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the question "How to read XML into a DataTable?". If yes, it's answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461123/how-to-read-xml-into-a-datatable

Comment: No the question is to query iqy file and store in datatable

Answer (score 0):

Read the third/last line of your .iqy file:

```
var url = File.ReadLines(@"query.iqy").Take(3).Last();
```

Then download the xml like using:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
   contents = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

And then parse the xml using `XDocument.Parse(contents)`, go through the xml and write the data to the database.