# How can i get data from xml file to datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, readfile, gridcontrol

I have a xml file like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Topic TopicName="FxhysS2vY64=">
  <Question>
    <QuestionID>HtjBCldKZg4=</QuestionID>
    <Details>Cg+MCbd9nTpJokauVrxHsyTqcvKCS8ePzHQCpUTVviWxAXriQVLy5w==</Details>
    <Description>x358GtJIXJI=</Description>
    <TrueOrFalse>D2zx2u5cwbo=</TrueOrFalse>
    <Points>W4VYuxBJeaY=</Points>
    <QuestionType>Fr1jj5tmWhMKNIKrHy18Rg==</QuestionType>
    <Caption>Cg+MCbd9nTpJokauVrxHsyTqcvKCS8ePAsNmzBfGJhg=</Caption>
    <TopicID>HtjBCldKZg4=</TopicID>
  </Question>
  <Question>
    <QuestionID>HtjBCldKZg4=</QuestionID>
    <Details>ccX0bHUdtg4ayF/7PfpFHUx9kPAGUBC5xOh1mw1b7d1g0lHifJ6AD49Niw1ipCPp</Details>
    <Description>x358GtJIXJI=</Description>
    <TrueOrFalse>JYEB3R1+ypE=</TrueOrFalse>
    <Points>W4VYuxBJeaY=</Points>
    <QuestionType>Fr1jj5tmWhMKNIKrHy18Rg==</QuestionType>
    <Caption>ccX0bHUdtg4ayF/7PfpFHUx9kPAGUBC5xOh1mw1b7d1g0lHifJ6AD49Niw1ipCPp</Caption>
    <TopicID>HtjBCldKZg4=</TopicID>
  </Question>
</Topic>
```

I want to put them into datatable and show in gridcontrol in devexpress
My gridcontrol
[image]

So, how can i do this. Thanks so much

Comment: Please refer to any online tutorial to do the basic coding and then ask specific questions.

Comment: Yeah, that is another "I am too lazy to learn what I am supposed to do, or read the documentation, please teach me programming" question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think it will help you

```
    public DataTable ReadXML(string file)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("XmlData");
    Stream stream = new  FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Power", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
    table.ReadXml(stream);
    return table;
}
```

Here is the full reference:

[How to read XML into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461123/how-to-read-xml-into-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simply method with very little work.  You are reading from a file so no need to use streams.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
        }
    }
}
```